# How to perform addition, update operation on extra table in identity server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

I have added the following UserLog table in the database using asnetidentity but i don't know how to perform add,update operation on the table.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

    public virtual ICollection<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }

}
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public Context(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
}
public class UserLog
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserLogID { get; set; }

    public string IPAD { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UserLog> UserLog { get; set; }
```

Like in the following code, I am using inbuilt methods of these aspnetidentity tables but how to add an entry in the "UserLog" table when user login every time in the following method?

```
public override async Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext ctx)
{
    var username = ctx.UserName;
    var password = ctx.Password;
    var message = ctx.SignInMessage;

    ctx.AuthenticateResult = null;

    if (userManager.SupportsUserPassword)
    {
        var user = await FindUserAsync(username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout &&
                await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            {
                if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
                }

                var result = await PostAuthenticateLocalAsync(user, message);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    var claims = await GetClaimsForAuthenticateResult(user);
                    result = new AuthenticateResult(user.Id.ToString(), await GetDisplayNameForAccountAsync(user.Id), claims);
                }

                ctx.AuthenticateResult = result;
            }
            else if (userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
            {
                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create an instance of UserLog

```
var userLog = new UserLog() { /* Set value for all the properties here */ };
```

**Step 2:** Add instance of `UserLog` to `DbContext`

```
context.Set<UserLog>().Add(userLog);
```

**Step 3:** Call [`DbContext.SaveChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) to save changes to database.

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Complete source code will looks like:

```
var userLog = new UserLog {
    UserLogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IPAD = "Some Value",
    LoginDate = DateTime.Now,
    UserId = "User Id Here"
};
var context = new Context();
context.Set<UserLogs>().Add(userLog);
context.SaveChanges();
```